# Update letsencrypt certificates without changing the private key

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, key, letsencrypt

I want to renew the letsencrypt certificate on my webserver but want to keep the private key same.

I've installed the certificate using `certbot 0.35.1`

How can I update the certificate (preferably using certbot) without changing the private key?

If possible can I automate this process, for auto renewal?

Comment: Why do you want to keep the key? It is more secure to rotate the key. Is the key pinned?

Answer (score 3):

Create a [certificate signing request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request) (CSR) and let certbot renew that, using a command like this:

```
certbot certonly --csr csr.pem
```

The CSR contains your public key, so you keep the same key pair with this method.